# Dired mode: Toggle show hidden files/folders by keyboard shortcut

Tags: dired

I am using Emacs 27.1 (`GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0)  of 2021-03-28, modified by Debian`) with "default" dired mode. There are no settings or extra packages related to dired mode in my `init.el`.

By default I see hidden (dotted) files and folders. Can I toggle that with a key shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your value of option `dired-listing-switches` (press <kbd>M-:</kbd> and type `dired-listing-switches`)? Customize it to use a value that does not list hidden files.  In other words, this is about the switches you tell Dired to use with `ls`.

You can also change the switches anytime, for a given Dired buffer, by invoking `dired` with a prefix arg (e.g. `C-u`).

For example, removing `a` from `dired-listing-switches` will likely do what you want: prevent listing files whose names start with `.`.

Comment: OK, it is `"-al" - I see. How do I use a "prefix arg"? This has no effect <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd>.

Comment: After `C-u`, do `M-x` and type `dired`. It will ask you the options to use.

Answer (score 5):

Bind a key to `dired-omit-mode` (you may need to require `dired-x` first) and set `dired-omit-files` something like this:

```
(setq dired-omit-files
    (rx (or (seq bol (? ".") "#")     ;; emacs autosave files
        (seq bol "." (not (any "."))) ;; dot-files
        (seq "~" eol)                 ;; backup-files
        (seq bol "CVS" eol)           ;; CVS dirs
        ))
```

Comment: `dired-omit-mode` can hide files by name regexp match, or by file extension, so yes, you could use option `dired-omit-files` (a regexp) to have `dired-omit-mode` omit files whose names begin with `.`.

Comment: @Drew: you are right.  Have edited accordingly.